# Appcelerator rich text editor

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Anyone knows a rich text editor for Titanium? I need to put text in bold, underlined and Italic.

Like trix editor that you can see in this link:
https://trix-editor.org/

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want such editor for writing code? I can hardly see anyone using such editors...

But there are the settings in Titanium Studio that you can apply to match your requirements like changing font and color of variables, strings, comments, function names, normal codes and much more. (this is what I prefer most)

Comment: @PrashantSaini I'm pretty sure he means in-app, not in studio. But I am not aware of any such editor. If you can find one in Objective-C you can write a module for it

Comment: @Rene, Yes I am also not aware of any such editor but there will surely be such editors on internet which can be used to write the code outside Studio which in turn will not allow to use the features of Studio.

Comment: I think that the only solutions is put an html editor into my app....

Comment: @amurica - you say "put an html editor into my app" as if that's a bad thing.  Why not just use trix.js within a webview?  It will very likely work.  Then you just have to use evalJS() and/or events to pass the rich text between the webview's editor and your application's code.

Comment: Yes, I'm using trix with Ti.APP.fireEvent()